# Problems with receiving 'utf-8' from client

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

I am trying to create a 2-way communication between server and client using `Flask` and `socket.io`.

Everything works fine until server receives `utf-8` string from client, which gets garbled. Sending from server to client works fine, and prior to sending from client to server, the client prints the message correctly.

Here is some code that reproduces the problem:

app.py:

```
import flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit, disconnect

import json

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
socket_io = SocketIO(app)

@socket_io.on('pull')
def socket_io_handle_pull():
    json_msg = {
        'msg': "abcćčddžđefghijklmnnjoprsštuvzž"
    }
    print("Pushing", json_msg)

    socket_io.emit('response', json_msg)

@socket_io.on('push')
def socket_io_handle_push(json_msg):
    print("Pushed:", json_msg)

@socket_io.on('disconnect')
def socket_io_handle_disconnect():
    disconnect()

@app.route('/')
def root():
    return flask.render_template(
        'index.html'
    )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socket_io.run(app)
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.3.6/socket.io.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);

      socket.on('response', json => {
        socket.emit('push', json);
      })

      socket.emit('pull');
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Output:

```
Pushing {'msg': 'abcćčddžđefghijklmnnjoprsštuvzž'}
Pushed: {'msg': 'abcÄ\x87Ä\x8dddA3Ä\x91efghijklmnnjoprsA!tuvzA3'}
```

Comment: Socket.IO uses JSON internally as a serialization mechanism. You do not need to JSON-encode yourself, just pass your string/list/dict objects freely and they'll get encoded and decoded when necessary.

Comment: @Miguel Oh, thank you for the insight! Should that fix the mojibake problem? It doesn't seem to when I tested it.

Comment: If you have a complete example I can use to reproduce the problem feel free to submit an issue on the github repo and I'll look at it.

Comment: I updated the question with code that reproduces the problem for me.

Comment: Does this still happen on a more recent Socket.IO client? They had bugs regarding utf-8 encoding in those old releases, try a 2.x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the 1.x versions of the Socket.IO client, which had [known problems](https://github.com/socketio/engine.io/issues/315) with double-encoding of UTF-8 strings. You should try the 2.x versions which have resolved this issue.

Comment: I updated to [socket.io 2.0.4](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/socket.io/2.0.4) and it works fine now! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I was getting back a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) decoded using `latin-1` and encoded with `utf-8`.

To fix this, I added:

`json_str = json_str.encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')`

If you are having this problem, take a look at [Miguel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49520583/4936137).

Answer (score 0):

I used servers socket.io js file from reverse proxy by adding socket.io.js end of reverse proxy path like this xxx.com/reverse_proxy_path/socket.io