# Passing foreign characters via Socket.IO

Tags: python, socket.io, character-encoding, flask-socketio, mojibake

I am doing a very simple thing, just sending a message to my Flask app via Socket.IO . It works like a charm with English, but some other languages break somewhere in the process.

Minimal working example follows.

testapp.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

app      = Flask('example')
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@socketio.on('test')
def on_connect(data):
    print(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script>
            var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000');
            socket.on('connect', function() {
                socket.emit('test', 'ASCII text');
                socket.emit('test', 'Český text');
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Instead of expected `Český text`, I am getting `ÄŚeskĂ˝ text` on the console.

I am using the newest versions of both the server packages (Flask-SocketIO 3.0.2, python-socketio 2.0.0, python-engineio 2.2.0) and the client (socket.io.js 2.1.1) and also checked that both of my files are UTF-8 encoded.

Some bug reports and [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49475762/problems-with-receiving-utf-8-from-client) mention a breaking change that happenned between 1.x and 2.x versions, so i tried using some older versions of the client (1.4.8, 1.7.4) instead of the newest one. The result was not much better: `ÃÅeskÄË text`.

This is beginners' stuff, so there must be a popular SO question covering it already. I probably just can't find it. So... what did I miss?