# Different socket.io responses from windows and linux

Tags: socket.io, flask-socketio

I'm using Flask-SocketIO and I'm seeing a different response from Windows (local) than I do from Linux (server).

Request: `/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NUnKB0b`

Windows Response: `0{"sid":"jnUgcaCw12uCvYTqAAAF","upgrades":["websocket"],"pingTimeout":5000,"pingInterval":25000}`

Linux Response:

```
\u00\n00\u00\n09\uff
0{"sid":"1aaf4b61ba7942b194190bfe783792f1","upgrades":["websocket"],"pingTimeout":60000,"pingInterval":25000}
\u00\u02\u04\uff42
["message","Test ZZZ"]
\u00\u02\uff\u34\u30
```

The differences being that the Linux Response includes a message and some binary decoration of the JSON.

Why does I get different results depending on the platform and is there a way to feed a hint to Flask_SocketIO to get a consistent result?

Comment: Just a guess, but this looks to me like it could be a unicode interpretation thing. I'm not sure what you can edit, but if you can change the server response to UTF-8, do that. If not, see if you can decode it as one of the standard unicode formats (UTF-16, 32, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading Flask-SocketIO on the Linux server fixed the Linux version of the message.

Thank you to Calculuswhiz for the UTF-8 hint which let me to the accepted answer of this question: [Problems with receiving 'utf-8' from client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49475762/problems-with-receiving-utf-8-from-client)